# When I check nginx access.log, unknown HEAD requests come in periodically

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx

First, I use the server environment:

1. sever: nginx + uwsgi + django app, docker + AWS ECS deploy
2. celery: rabbitmq ec2
3. cache: redis ec2
4. logging: AWS CloudWatch log + watchtower third party app

When I access ECS EC2 and check nginx access.log, the following request periodically comes in.
Why is this request coming to me? This is what keeps coming in the first time you open the server.

In addition, my ecs server's security group 80/443 ports are opened to anywhere.

### nginx/access.log

```
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:12 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/mysql/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:12 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/mysql/dbadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:12 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/mysql/sqlmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:12 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/mysql/mysqlmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:13 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:13 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpMyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:13 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:13 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpmyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:13 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpmyadmin2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:13 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpmyadmin3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:13 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpmyadmin4/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:13 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/2phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:13 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/wp-content/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/wp-pma-mod/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:13 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpmy/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:14 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phppma/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:14 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/myadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:14 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/shopdb/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:14 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/MyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:14 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/program/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:14 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/PMA/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:14 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/dbadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:14 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/pma/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:14 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/db/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:15 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:15 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/mysql/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:15 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/database/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:15 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/db/phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:15 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/db/phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:15 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/sqlmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:15 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/mysqlmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:15 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/php-myadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:15 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpmy-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:16 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/mysqladmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:16 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/mysql-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:16 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/admin/phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:16 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/admin/phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:16 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/admin/sysadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:16 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/admin/sqladmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:16 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/admin/db/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:16 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/admin/web/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:16 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/admin/pMA/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:17 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/mysql/pma/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:17 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/mysql/db/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:17 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/mysql/web/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:17 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/mysql/pMA/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:17 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/sql/phpmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:17 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/sql/php-myadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:17 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/sql/phpmy-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:17 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/sql/sql/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:17 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/sql/myadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:18 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/sql/webadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:18 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/sql/sqlweb/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:18 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/sql/websql/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:18 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/sql/webdb/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:18 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/sql/sqladmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:18 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/sql/sql-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:18 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/sql/phpmyadmin2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:18 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/sql/phpMyAdmin2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:18 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/sql/phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:19 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/db/myadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:19 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/db/webadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:19 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/db/dbweb/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:19 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/db/websql/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:19 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/db/webdb/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:19 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/db/dbadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:19 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/db/db-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:19 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/db/phpmyadmin3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:19 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/db/phpMyAdmin3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:20 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/db/phpMyAdmin-3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:20 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/administrator/phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:20 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/administrator/phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:20 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/administrator/db/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:20 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/administrator/web/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:20 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/administrator/pma/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:20 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/administrator/PMA/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:20 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/administrator/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:20 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpMyAdmin2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:20 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpMyAdmin3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:21 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpMyAdmin4/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:21 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpMyAdmin-3/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:21 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/php-my-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:21 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/PMA2011/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:21 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/PMA2012/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:21 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/PMA2013/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:21 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/PMA2014/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:21 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/PMA2015/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:21 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/PMA2016/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:22 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/PMA2017/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:22 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/PMA2018/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:22 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/pma2011/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:22 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/pma2012/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:22 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/pma2013/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:22 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/pma2014/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:22 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/pma2015/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:22 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/pma2016/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:22 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/pma2017/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:23 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/pma2018/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:23 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpmyadmin2011/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:23 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpmyadmin2012/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:23 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpmyadmin2013/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:23 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpmyadmin2015/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:23 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpmyadmin2016/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:23 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpmyadmin2017/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:24 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpmyadmin2018/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
54.214.101.194 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:02:24 +0000] "HEAD http://13.114.17.75:80/phpmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
95.213.177.125 - - [14/Jul/2017:03:14:35 +0000] "POST /azenv.php?auth=150000207593&a=PSCMN&i=885409785&p=80 HTTP/1.1" 404 580 "https://proxyradar.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)"
```

Comment: Who is 10.0.1.234?

Comment: @Fabien hmm.. I send a request to the API in my office, and the IP is also recorded as 10.0.1.234.

Comment: @Fabien maybe that is ELB's IP

Comment: That might be the IP address of their ELB indeed. In which case all of this looks like an enumeration of a vulnerability scanner looking for weak targets. Just a random scan like there are thousands.

Comment: @Fabien change logging ip address, that ip is flexible

Comment: @Fabien Does your feedback mean that ELB scans randomly to identify weaknesses? So, is there any security problem?

Comment: No, external hackers are scanning your domains, but don't worry it's Internet's usual stuff.

Comment: @Fabien I got it thank you!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a very typical request pattern from the vulnerability scanning tool [ZmEu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZmEu_(vulnerability_scanner)). Long story short a hacker is running an automated tool that is trying to find a vulnerable installation of PHPMyAdmin on your system, to exploit it in order to gain root access to your system. It doesn't even matter that you don't have PHPMyAdmin on your system, they will still make requests just to test and see if you do because its cheap to do so, and if they do find something to exploit they can get into your server to steal data or use it for nefarious purposes.

Unfortunately this is just the cost of having a server on the internet, people are constantly running automated scanning tools against any server they can reach, trying to find ways to hack into it and take it over.

Comment: Can we mitigate these "attacks" using fail2ban?

Comment: Yes, but for something like this its generally not worth it to introduce the extra overhead. Serving a 404 back to the attacker costs you practically nothing. Checking and verifying all inbound IP addresses against a database of banned IP's costs a lot more.